# App that works as iBeacon. How to be discovered even with the app has terminated?

Tags: ios, background, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I'm trying to use iBeacon in background mode and works fine, but I want that the app works when has been terminated by the system. It's possible to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your title says "app that works as iBeacon" - if that it taken literally to mean that your app causes the device to advertise as an iBeacon, then this is only supported when the app runs in the foreground.  However, if you mean detecting other devices/phones which transmit iBeacon packets, that works when the user has not specifically terminated the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to write your app so it launches into the background when LocationServices sees an iBeacon, even if your app is terminated.  See my answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19128781/1461050

Answer (score 0):

It should just work, unless the user removes the app. It's not the app itself that shows the beacon, it is the operating system showing the beacon on behalf of the app. That doesn't change when the OS terminates the app, only if the user does it.