# Presenting UILocalNotification not showing banner immediately

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

Hi I am pushing 3 local notification one by one in a 3 second gap. I am getting 1st notification immediately after push it but rest of the notifications came after few minutes. I went through few documents and blogs but all are pushing the same way in which I am doing in my application. Please help me to resolve this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Here my code to push the notification

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [UILocalNotification new];

// Notification details
notification.alertBody = message;   
notification.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View", nil);
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
notification.userInfo = info;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
```

Comment: The code you posted works, as you said yourself. Please post your code related to the time setting for the other notifications

Comment: There is no time setting. I am pushing the notification when device get into iBeacon range. If application in foreground, i am getting the notifications immediately, but not getting in the background

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127282/ibeacon-notification-when-the-app-is-not-running

Comment: have you wrapper your execution with a background handler?

Comment: Have you set plist value for the background support of the application ?