# Beacon Notification when the app is not running on Android

Tags: android, ios, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I am aware if it is possible to wake up an app when the user is close it a beacon. It know it is [possible to do it on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127282/ibeacon-notification-when-the-app-is-not-running). I have not found a clear solution on the web. Do you know if it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with the open source [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/).  It works by starting a low-power background beacon scanning service for your app when the phone boots, or when it is connected/disconnected from power.

Details about how you set this up, how it works, and its limitations are available [here.](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/background_launching.html)

Comment: So this answer kind of skirts the real question IMO.  If the Android Beacon Library is starting a service when it the phone boots or is charging, then the app is running, just not with a visible Activity.  If the user were to force close the app it would stop scanning.  Does seem like a reasonable solution because the user is unlikely to even know it is running.  Big concern is the battery drain which I do not know how much of a drain this would be.