# Keep Monitoring BLE when Application is killed in iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

**How to keep monitoring `BLE` when application is killed?**

My apps is running in background, but not running when I killed it.
I have background modes:
`ble-peripheral`, `ble-central`, `location`, `background fetch`.

Comment: There is no way to run iOS app once it's killed!

Comment: then how about whatsapp? it  can send notification when apps is killed

Comment: WhatsApp like apps uses [APNS](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/)  and [VoIP Pushes](https://developer.apple.com/reference/pushkit) which can awake app silently in background

Comment: See this: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/75403 - Take care of the "State Preservation and Restoration" - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW14

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127282/ibeacon-notification-when-the-app-is-not-running

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iBeacon Notification when the app is not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127282/ibeacon-notification-when-the-app-is-not-running)